# Javascript string concatenate in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to generate a character from these three arrays. My code is as follows, but I can't figure out why the string doesn't concatenate as I've written. Some of it is missing, and the ending `.` even comes at the start at some times. Occasionally it works, but a lot of the times the output fails.

```
//Arrays
var character = ["man", "woman"];
var feature = ["one leg", "a drinking problem"];
var purpose = ["stay home", "leave home"];

function createSentence(){
    var char = getRandomItem(character);
    var feat = getRandomItem(feature);
    var purp = getRandomItem(purpose);
    var sentence = "A " + char + " with " + feat + ", that wants to " + purp + ".";
    return sentence;
}

// Gets a random item from an input array
function getRandomItem(array){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
    return array[index];
}
```

Here's what I get in my console. `.` at the start and missing the "character"-part.

> .with a drinking problem, that wants to leave home

**EDIT:** Sorry for not including this, as I guess this is very relevant here as well. I assumed the arrays were fine, but I might be missing something. When I print out the arrays after parsing them they look exactly like what I posted above.

```
// How i set up my arrays
var character = parseTextFile("character.txt");
var feature = parseTextFile("feature.txt");
var purpose = parseTextFile("purpose .txt");

// Parsing a file
function parseTextFile(filename){
    var array = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString().split("\n");
    return array;
}

/* --- character.txt ---*/
man
woman
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have the inpression that `char`is a reserved keyword, which then mess up your concatenation, try to rename it.

Comment: It appears [to work fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rC4To.png) - can you show how you're actually calling it and displaying your output?

Comment: @DrakaSAN no it's not, there is no `char` in javascript

Comment: Yes, it works very fine

Comment: @JamesThorpe Interesting. I had to try myself and surprisingly enough the code I posted here seems to work at my computer as well. I will include some more source in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// How i set up my arrays
var character = parseTextFile("character.txt");
var feature = parseTextFile("feature.txt");
var purpose = parseTextFile("purpose .txt");

// Parsing a file
function parseTextFile(filename){
    //fs.read requires absolute path
    var array = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + filename, 'utf8') // <-- specify format
        .split('\n')
        .filter(function(text) { return !!text; }); // <-- return only not-empty string
    return array;
}
```